# How Similar Are Two Words

Tags: string, algorithm

is there more accurate algorithm than "Levenshtein distance" algorithm??
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

Comment: It depends on how you define accuracy.

Comment: Why is Levenshtein inappropriate for you?

Comment: What notion of similarity are you after? Without knowing what you want, it's impossible to suggest other measures.

Comment: @DanielFischer Levenshtein returns bad results with short words <br>
for example I am searching a file for similar words to a given word<br>, I checked the algorithm on each word in the file , if it return int is less that 3 the it is similar , It works for large words but with small words it wont
when I search for the word "one" similar words are "core , line ,open ,move, long ,code"

Comment: @AymanJitan: You need to compare the editing distance relative to both words' lengths (min, max, avg, your choice). (updated my answer)

Comment: @Regexident I tried that but it is does not give the required accuracy with too short words , but with other words it works very fine 
for example if I was searching for similar words to the word "programme" it returns "program" and that is perfect but not with too small words

Comment: @AymanJitan: Well, that's simply caused by the lack of precision when measuring similarity of short words, as a word of length 4 can only have 5 possible similarities with any other given word: 0%, 25%, 50%, 75%, 100%. There's not much you can do about it. The only thing that would come to my mind would be to use some kind of dampening of the allowed variance using a logarithmic scale.

Comment: @Regexident I think you are right it is lack of precision when measuring similarity of short words , I used a static precision all the time , it needs to be dynamic
Thank you

Comment: Well, in terms of edit distance, all short words are rather similar, there's no way around it. Scaling according to the length, as Regexident suggested may give satisfactory results, otherwise you need to find a clear specification of the similarity you desire.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the [**Damerau–Levenshtein distance**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance), which adds support for character transpositions and providing more coverage for common typos.

To get a similarity percentage for **Levenshtein** or **Damerau-Levenshtein** do something like this:

```
int relative_similarity = 1.0 - 1.0 / ((len(x) + len(y)) / 2) * lev(x, y); //untested
```

Alternatively you might want to take a look at the [**longest common subsequence**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) as a metric of similarity.

Next there are

- [Soundex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex)
- [Metaphone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphone)
- [Double Metaphone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphone#Double_Metaphone)

which are phonetic matching algorithms.

While `Smith` and its german counterpart `Schmidt` would turn up as quite different using the edit distance (a.k.a Levenshtein), Soundex and MEtaphone would consider them phonetically similar or even equivalent.

---

But without you telling us what's *wrong* about the pure **Levenshtein distance** it's hard to guess a better algorithm.

Comment: Damerau–Levenshtein distance is more accurate that the (classic) Levenshtein <br>
Levenshtein returns bad results with sort words

Comment: @AymanJitan: Damerau-Levenshtein also is not a true text metric (as it does not meet the triangle inequality), which in case of BKTrees, e.g. can be a rather bad thing. Without you giving us more information on what's wrong with the common algorithms, it's kind of impossible to provide helpful recommendations. "Similar" could mean just about anything: wordlength, wordshape, phonetics, semantic meaning, …